# How to know the branch of a tag using SVNKit java API?

Tags: svnkit

Can someone please tell me how to figure out branch of an svn tag? Would be great if there is any working code, that gets me branches for certain tags? Thanks.

I use this command line command as of now to see it on console

svn log -v -l 2 "path to tag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

```
ISVNLogEntryHandler handler = new ISVNLogEntryHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleLogEntry(SVNLogEntry arg0) throws     SVNException {
                    Map<String, SVNLogEntryPath> map = arg0.getChangedPaths();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, SVNLogEntryPath> entry: map.entrySet()) {
                        SVNLogEntryPath svnLogEntryPath = entry.getValue();
                         System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        System.out.println("Path : " + svnLogEntryPath.getPath());
                        System.out.println("Kind : " + svnLogEntryPath.getKind());
                        System.out.println("Type : " + svnLogEntryPath.getType());
                        System.out.println("Copy Path : " + svnLogEntryPath.getCopyPath()); // gives the tag's branch
                        System.out.println("Branch : " + svnLogEntryPath.getCopyPath().substring(svnLogEntryPath.getCopyPath().lastIndexOf('/')+1)); // gives the tag's branch
                        System.out.println("Copy Revision : " + svnLogEntryPath.getCopyRevision());

                        System.out.println("------------------------");
                    }   
                }
            }; 
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(userName, password);

boolean readonly = true;
            ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(readonly);

            // Get log client
            SVNLogClient logClient = new SVNLogClient(authManager, options);

String[] paths = { pathToTag};

logClient.doLog(svnurl, paths, SVNRevision.HEAD, startRevision, SVNRevision.HEAD, true, true, 2, handler);
```